# SQLite No such table while INSERT INTO

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I need help in my code. I am trying to save text into SQLite database but it says no such table although I've already declared.

WordDatabase.java

```
package com.fyp.atms;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class WordDatabase {

    public static final String WORD_ID = "_id";
    public static final String WORD_TOTRANSLATE = "to_translate";
    public static final String WORD_TRANSLATED = "translated";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WordHistory";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "WordTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private Database db;
    private final Context cont;
    private SQLiteDatabase HistoryDatabase;

    public static class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public Database(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    WORD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                    WORD_TOTRANSLATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                    WORD_TRANSLATED + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }


    }

    public WordDatabase(Context con){
        cont = con;
    }

    public WordDatabase open() throws Exception{
        db = new Database(cont);
        HistoryDatabase = db.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        db.close();
    }

    public void createEntry(String beforeTranslate, String afterTranslate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(WORD_TOTRANSLATE, beforeTranslate);
        content.put(WORD_TRANSLATED, afterTranslate);
        HistoryDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, content);
    }

    public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String[] col = new String[]{WORD_ID, WORD_TOTRANSLATE, WORD_TRANSLATED};
        Cursor curs = HistoryDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, null, null, null, null, null);
        String res = "";
        int rowNum = curs.getColumnIndex(WORD_ID);
        int toTranslateNum = curs.getColumnIndex(WORD_TOTRANSLATE);
        int TranslatedNum = curs.getColumnIndex(WORD_TRANSLATED);

        for(curs.moveToFirst(); !curs.isAfterLast(); curs.moveToNext()){
            res = res + curs.getString(rowNum) + " " + curs.getString(toTranslateNum) + "          " + curs.getString(TranslatedNum) + "\n";
        }

        return res;
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java - onClickListener

```
        try{
            String beforeTranslate = toTl.getText().toString();
            String afterTranslate = tled.getText().toString();

            WordDatabase newEntry = new WordDatabase(MainActivity.this);
            newEntry.open();
            newEntry.createEntry(beforeTranslate, afterTranslate);
            newEntry.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Wordhistory.java

```
package com.fyp.atms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Wordhistory extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wordhistory);

        TextView d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HistoryData);
        WordDatabase words = new WordDatabase(this);

        try{
            words.open();
            String data = words.getData();
            words.close();
            d.setText(data);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the LogCat

```
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteLog(25675): (1) no such table: WordTable
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675): Error inserting translated=你好 to_translate=hello
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: WordTable (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO WordTable(translated,to_translate) VALUES (?,?)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at com.fyp.atms.WordDatabase.createEntry(WordDatabase.java:70)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at com.fyp.atms.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:109)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4447)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18445)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:805)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
10-22 01:33:51.884: E/SQLiteDatabase(25675):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 01:34:57.564: I/MiuiCursorController(25675): InsertionPointCursorController is hidden including all panels and handle
```

Comment: make sure `WorlTable` is created.

Comment: I thought i already created it in onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run